# How do I unquote/process json array in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following query:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT('{"ids": ["a", "b", "c"]}'), '$.ids')
```

which returns:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want to process this to obtain unquoted result. What is exactly want to achieve is:

```
a b c
```

Though

```
[a, b, c]
```

is also ok.

I tried to use `JSON_UNQUOTE`, but it does not work on tested entries:

```
 > select JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT('{"ids": ["a", "b", "c"]}', '$.ids') 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT('{"ids": ["a", "b", "c"]}', '$.ids') ) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["a", "b", "c"]                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Because JSON_EXTRACT returns a string you can remove the quotes with REPLACE

Comment: @RaymondNijland What if one of the items in the array already contain `"`?

Comment: True that's possible in JSON that double qoutes are escapsed within keys and values.. Then you have a problem.. Unless you are using MySQL 8.0 which supports a REGEX replace..